# Syncing between a windows based server (host) and linux server(client) using SFTP

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, sftp

My task is to sync folders between two computers. One which acts as a windows server which is the host and the other one is a linux based server. The file transfer has to be secure and encrypted. Are there are any free softwares which will help me do this task. 
Additionally the syncing should automatically happen after every pre decided interval.

Answer (score 1):

I have a recollection that WinSCP can be invoked through command line. There, you have the option to synchronize folders (and the whole hierarchy there in). It may be worth trying.

Total Commander also has FTP/SFTP capabilities, but I'm not sure you can invoke it through command line.

One point to consider: If the process is to run automatically, you need to hard-code the username and password for the connection. There your security becomes compromised.